# How to ask this question. Which one have the most morality?

Tags: best-most

What is the correct use of this? May Both be wrong?

**Which one have the most morality?**

or

**Which one have the most morale?**

Comment: It should be ***has*** in any case.  Are you talking about morals or morale? They’re different.

Comment: Yep, it's important to understand that "moral" and "morale" are two completely different words.

Comment: I guess i mean MORAL but dictionary shows the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following alternatives:

- Who demonstrates the highest moral values?
- Who displays the highest ethical standards?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest version would be "Which one is the most moral?"

As for your choices, since the subject "which" is singular, both should use "has" rather than "have".

Morality is the quality of being moral. Morale is [the capacity of a group's members to maintain belief in an institution or goal, particularly in the face of opposition or hardship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morale). So, assuming you were talking about morality, the second choice is entirely wrong.